# Send Bidimensional Array from Php to Javascript using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I want to pass this php array to Javascript by ajax

This is my main.php file which contains the array :

```
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);
    for ($i=0; $i<$entries["count"]; $i++)
    {
      if (isset($entries[$i]["cn"][0])) {
        $res [$i][0]=$entries[$i]["cn"][0];
      }else {
        $res [$i][0]="";
      }
      if (isset($entries[$i]["ipphone"][0])) {
        $res [$i][1]=$entries[$i]["ipphone"][0];
      }else {
        $res [$i][1]="";
      }
      if (isset($entries[$i]["telephonenumber"][0])) {
        $res [$i][2]=$entries[$i]["telephonenumber"][0];
      }else {
        $res [$i][2]="";
      }
      if (isset($entries[$i]["mobile"][0])) {
        $res [$i][3]=$entries[$i]["mobile"][0];
      }else {
        $res [$i][3]="";
      }
      if (isset($entries[$i]["homephone"][0])) {
        $res [$i][4]=$entries[$i]["homephone"][0];
      }else {
        $res [$i][4]="";
      }
       if (isset($entries[$i][""][0])) {
        $res [$i][5]=$entries[$i][""][0];
       }else {
        $res [$i][5]="";
      }
      if (isset($entries[$i]["description"][0])) {
        $res [$i][6]=$entries[$i]["description"][0];
      }else {
        $res [$i][6]="";
      }
      if (isset($entries[$i]["mail"][0])) {
        $res [$i][7]=$entries[$i]["mail"][0];
      }else {
        $res [$i][7]="";
      }
      if (isset($entries[$i]["facsimiletelephonenumber"][0])) {
        $res [$i][8]=$entries[$i]["facsimiletelephonenumber"][0];
      }else {
        $res [$i][8]="";
      }
    }
ldap_close($ldap);
```

And this is my main.js file , i want to get the array with ajax

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                array = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "main.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

The idea is to work like this with the array but i

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        $("#tabla").append("<tr class='usuario'></tr>");
        $(".usuario:last").append("<td class='Nombre'>" + res[i][0] + "</td>");
        $(".usuario:last").append("<td class='ExtFij'>" + res[i][1] + "</td>");
        $(".usuario:last").append("<td class='NumFij'>" + res[i][2] + "</td>");
        $(".usuario:last").append("<td class='ExtMov'>" + res[i][3] + "</td>");
        $(".usuario:last").append("<td class='NumMov'>" + res[i][4] + "</td>");
        $(".usuario:last").append("<td class='TalDel'>" + res[i][5] + "</td>");
        $(".usuario:last").append("<td class='Cargo'>" + res[i][6] + "</td>");
        $(".usuario:last").append("<td class='CorSol'>" + res[i][7] + "</td>");
        $(".usuario:last").append("<td class='CorVent'>" + res[i][8] + "</td>");
    }
```

The main problem is that im still learning how to work with ajax , i have tried a lot of ways but i didnt get any solution 
Thanks in advance

Edit 1:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                array = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                alert("1 " + array[0][0]);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "main.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        alert("2 " + array[0][0]);
```

Comment: Your `main.php` does not seem to output anything, so nothing arrives at the JS side. Try `echo json_encode($res);` at the end and see what arrives at your JS side.

Comment: Thanks it looks that now works but i cant acces to the array before the xmlhttp request i mean i can acces on the 1st alert but not in the 2

Comment: It's asynchronous (the 1st A in AJAX). You can trigger a callback in your response function (eg. where alert-1 is located) to fill the table with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your array output in JSON and send it to using AJAX and also you have to define content type is JSON.

you can also use jquery ajax it is very simple for request response.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url:"URL here",
    success: function(data) // response 
    {}
});
```

Comment: Holy sh*t men ! this is... is too much  now works so cool and quick